# How does a contract know which library to query or know the library address?

Tags: contract-development, addresses, library, delegatecall

How does a contract know which library to query? For Example in the code below (The code is from solidity docs: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/contracts.html?highlight=library#libraries

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.22;

library Set {
  // We define a new struct datatype that will be used to
  // hold its data in the calling contract.
  struct Data { mapping(uint => bool) flags; }

  // Note that the first parameter is of type "storage
  // reference" and thus only its storage address and not
  // its contents is passed as part of the call.  This is a
  // special feature of library functions.  It is idiomatic
  // to call the first parameter `self`, if the function can
  // be seen as a method of that object.
  function insert(Data storage self, uint value)
      public
      returns (bool)
  {
      if (self.flags[value])
          return false; // already there
      self.flags[value] = true;
      return true;
  }

  function remove(Data storage self, uint value)
      public
      returns (bool)
  {
      if (!self.flags[value])
          return false; // not there
      self.flags[value] = false;
      return true;
  }

  function contains(Data storage self, uint value)
      public
      view
      returns (bool)
  {
      return self.flags[value];
  }
}

contract C {
    Set.Data knownValues;

    function register(uint value) public {
        // The library functions can be called without a
        // specific instance of the library, since the
        // "instance" will be the current contract.
        require(Set.insert(knownValues, value));
    }
    // In this contract, we can also directly access knownValues.flags, if we want.
}
```

How does Contract C know where the Set library is located and what if there are other libraries called Set?

Is there something missing in this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the same document, it says:

> As the compiler cannot know where the library will be deployed at,
>   these addresses have to be filled into the final bytecode by a linker

and goes on to explain how to do that.